# AngularJS - Function not being instantiated from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a simple deferred promise. But I keep getting this error:

`MainModel.getNato is not a function`

I have a view controller specifiec in the **index.html** as such:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ui-view="mainview"></div>
  </body>
```

and then in that `ui-view` of **mainview** is in **main.template.html**:

```
<div class="service" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>NATO Alphabet via Promise</h1>
  {{mainCtrl.hello}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="nato in mainCtrl.natoAlphabet">{{ nato }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With **app.js** being:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('TestApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'testapp.models.main',
  ])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('testapp', {
        url: '',
        views: {
          'mainview@': {
            controller: 'MainCtrl as mainCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'main.template.html'
          }
        }
      });
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl($scope, MainModel) {
    this.natoAlphabet = MainModel.getNato();
    // comment the line above to make the view appear
    this.hello = MainModel.hello;
  });
```

and its model controller of **main.model.js** being:

```
angular.module('testapp.models.main', [])
  .service('MainModel', function($q) {

    var getNato = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      deferred.resolve(['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot', 'Golf', 'Hotel', 'India']);

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.getNato = getNato();

    this.hello = "Hello world!";

  });
```

Pretty simple stuff, right?

However I am getting

```
TypeError: MainModel.getNato is not a function
    at new MainCtrl (app.js:20)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4523)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9182)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8299)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7731)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7734)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7611)
    at angular.js:1681
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16152)
```

See this code live at: http://plnkr.co/edit/AcLK69KIkmkAh26Orsev?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
this.getNato = getNato();
```

Is assigning the result of `getNato` to your service - you want to assign the function, so omit the `()`

```
this.getNato = getNato;
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I did that and, for whatever reason, it still is not showing up in the `ng-repeat` and doing `{{mainCtrl.natoAlphabet}}` shows up empty.

Comment: @djp -- Isn't it supposed to be `<div class="service" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">` (notice the `as mainCtrl`)?

Comment: It is defined in the `app.js`'s `$stateProvider`'s view. But I did that change and still nothing. And no error. Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/AcLK69KIkmkAh26Orsev?p=preview

Comment: @djp -- `this.natoAlphabet` is a promise, you have to resolve it yet: http://plnkr.co/edit/0jyRpGCfdB9HaG3ikCFn?p=preview

Comment: AHHH! Yes. Thank you. One last question. Why do I need `var self = this;`? Why cannot I not just do `this.natoAlphabet` inside the `MainModel.getNato.then(function(data) {...`?

Comment: @djp -- The context of `this` changes once you're inside the callback function. the `var self = this;` is just to preserve the context.

Comment: Oh I see. And I assume that wouldn't impose of any mocked unit tests with such deferred promises.

Answer (score 1):

You already assign a function in `var getNato` so assign only `getNato` variable in `this.getNato`

like:

```
this.getNato = getNato
```

Answer (score 0):

building on @tymeJV, I would clean it this way

```
angular.module('testapp.models.main', [])
  .service('MainModel', function($q) {

    var getNato = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      deferred.resolve(['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot', 'Golf', 'Hotel', 'India']);

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    var service =  {

    getNato : getNato,
    hello : "Hello world!"

    }

    return service;

  });
```

Comment: Tried this in plunker and understood the methodology. But I think, the `getNato = getNato;` should be `getNato: getNato,`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified as:

```
angular.module('testapp.models.main', [])
  .service('MainModel', function($q) {

    this.getNato = $q.when(['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie',
                            'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot',
                            'Golf', 'Hotel', 'India']);

    this.hello = "Hello world!";

});
```

And yes, `getNato` is not a function, it's a promise.

To resolve it, use the promise's `.then` method.

```
var vm=this;
MainModel.getNato.then (function (result) {
     vm.natoAlphabet = result;
});
```